# What is pipes/conduit trying to solve

Tags: haskell, pipe, conduit, haskell-pipes

I have seen people recommending pipes/conduit library for various lazy IO related tasks. What problem do these libraries solve exactly?

Also, when I try to use some hackage related libraries, it is highly likely there are three different versions. Example:

- [attoparsec](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec)
- [pipes-attoparsec](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-attoparsec)
- [attoparsec-conduit](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec-conduit)

This confuses me. For my parsing tasks should I use attoparsec or pipes-attoparsec/attoparsec-conduit? What benefit do the pipes/conduit version give me as compared to the plain vanilla attoparsec?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

## Lazy IO

Lazy IO works like this

```
readFile :: FilePath -> IO ByteString
```

where `ByteString` is guaranteed to only be read chunk-by-chunk. To do so we could (almost) write

```
-- given `readChunk` which reads a chunk beginning at n
readChunk :: FilePath -> Int -> IO (Int, ByteString)

readFile fp = readChunks 0 where
  readChunks n = do
    (n', chunk) <- readChunk fp n
    chunks      <- readChunks n'
    return (chunk <> chunks)
```

but here we note that the IO action `readChunks n'` is performed prior to returning even the partial result available as `chunk`. This means we're not lazy at all. To combat this we use `unsafeInterleaveIO`

```
readFile fp = readChunks 0 where
  readChunks n = do
    (n', chunk) <- readChunk fp n
    chunks      <- unsafeInterleaveIO (readChunks n')
    return (chunk <> chunks)
```

which causes `readChunks n'` to return immediately, thunking an *`IO` action* to be performed only when that thunk is forced.

That's the dangerous part: by using `unsafeInterleaveIO` we've delayed a bunch of `IO` actions to non-deterministic points in the future that depend upon how we consume our chunks of `ByteString`.

## Fixing the problem with coroutines

What we'd like to do is slide a chunk processing step in between the call to `readChunk` and the recursion on `readChunks`.

```
readFileCo :: Monoid a => FilePath -> (ByteString -> IO a) -> IO a
readFileCo fp action = readChunks 0 where
  readChunks n = do
    (n', chunk) <- readChunk fp n
    a           <- action chunk
    as          <- readChunks n'
    return (a <> as)
```

Now we've got the chance to perform arbitrary `IO` actions after each small chunk is loaded. This lets us do much more work incrementally without completely loading the `ByteString` into memory. Unfortunately, it's not terrifically compositional--we need to build our consumption `action` and pass it to our `ByteString` producer in order for it to run.

## Pipes-based IO

This is essentially what `pipes` solves--it allows us to compose effectful co-routines with ease. For instance, we now write our file reader as a `Producer` which can be thought of as "streaming" the chunks of the file when its effect gets run finally.

```
produceFile :: FilePath -> Producer ByteString IO ()
produceFile fp = produce 0 where
  produce n = do
    (n', chunk) <- liftIO (readChunk fp n)
    yield chunk
    produce n'
```

Note the similarities between this code and `readFileCo` above—we simply replace the call to the coroutine action with `yield`ing the `chunk` we've produced so far. This call to `yield` builds a `Producer` type instead of a raw `IO` action which we can compose with other `Pipe`s types in order to build a nice consumption pipeline called an `Effect IO ()`.

All of this pipe building gets done statically without actually invoking any of the `IO` actions. This is how `pipes` lets you write your coroutines more easily. All of the effects get triggered at once when we call `runEffect` in our `main` `IO` action.

```
runEffect :: Effect IO () -> IO ()
```

## Attoparsec

So why would you want to plug `attoparsec` into `pipes`? Well, `attoparsec` is optimized for lazy parsing. If you are producing the chunks fed to an `attoparsec` parser in an effectful way then you'll be at an impasse. You could

1. Use strict IO and load the entire string into memory only to consume it lazily with your parser. This is simple, predictable, but inefficient.
2. Use lazy IO and lose the ability to reason about when your production IO effects will actually get run causing possible resource leaks or closed handle exceptions according to the consumption schedule of your parsed items. This is more efficient than (1) but can easily become unpredictable; or,
3. Use `pipes` (or `conduit`) to build up a system of coroutines which include your lazy `attoparsec` parser allowing it to operate on as little input as it needs while producing parsed values as lazily as possible across the entire stream.

Comment: Thanks, what is `<>` operator in the `readChunks` functions ? Hoogle didn't help.

Comment: Sorry, that the `Monoid` of lazy ByteString. The idea should be that lazy ByteStrings are just lazy lists of strict ByteStrings, so `(<>)` is nothing more than `(++)` on those lists.

Comment: @Sibi Probably infix `mappend`. Hayoo! can find it: http://holumbus.fh-wedel.de/hayoo/hayoo.html?query=%3C%3E

Comment: Regarding Point 1 in attoparsec section, what do you mean by strict IO there ? Does that refer to the original `readFile` function without `unsafeInterleaveIO` which reads the entire file into memory ?

Comment: @Sibi Yep exactly. For more exploration of this, consider [Joachim Breitner's "How to Construct a List in a Monad"](https://www.joachim-breitner.de/blog/archives/620-Constructing-a-list-in-a-Monad.html). In particular, examine the problem he outlines (and offers no clear solution to) as being exactly the kind of think `pipes` and `conduit` solve.

Comment: This isn't really key to the rest, but the `unsafeInterleaveIO` needs to be further out; lazy IO is lazy from the start.

Comment: @dfeuer I realized that error too, so I'm glad you memorialized it. I was hoping it was more clear in the slightly-to-strict form, despite incorrectness.

Answer (score 19):

## If you want to use attoparsec, use attoparsec

> For my parsing tasks should I use attoparsec or pipes-attoparsec/attoparsec-conduit?

Both `pipes-attoparsec` and `attoparsec-conduit` transform a given `attoparsec` `Parser` into a sink/conduit or pipe. Therefore you have to use `attoparsec` either way.

> What benefit do the pipes/conduit version give me as compared to the plain vanilla attoparsec?

They work with pipes and conduit, where the vanilla one won't (at least not out-of-the-box).

If you don't use conduit or pipes, and you're satisfied with the current performance of your lazy IO, there's no need to change your current flow, especially if you're not writing a big application or process large files. You can simply use `attoparsec`.

However, that assumes that you know the drawbacks of lazy IO.

## What's the matter with lazy IO? (Problem study `withFile`)

Lets not forget your first question:

> What problem do these libraries solve exactly ?

They solve the streaming data problem (see [1](http://www.haskellforall.com/2014/02/reasoning-about-stream-programming.html) and [3](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Iteratee_I/O)), that occurs within functional languages with lazy IO. Lazy IO sometimes gives you not what you want (see example below), and sometimes it's hard to determine the actual system resources needed by a specific lazy operation (is the data read/written in chunks/bytes/buffered/onclose/onopen…).

### Example for over-laziness

```
import System.IO
main = withFile "myfile" ReadMode hGetContents
       >>= return . (take 5)
       >>= putStrLn
```

This won't print anything, since the evaluation of the data happens in `putStrLn`, but the handle has been closed already at this point.

### Fixing fire with poisonous acid

While the following snippet fixes this, it has another nasty feature:

```
main = withFile "myfile" ReadMode $ \handle -> 
           hGetContents handle
       >>= return . (take 5)
       >>= putStrLn
```

In this case `hGetContents` will read **all of the file**, something you didn't expect at first. If you just want to check the magic bytes of a file which could be several GB in size, this is not the way to go.

### Using `withFile` correctly

The solution is, obviously, to `take` the things in the `withFile` context:

```
main = withFile "myfile" ReadMode $ \handle -> 
           fmap (take 5) (hGetContents handle)
       >>= putStrLn
```

This is by the way, also the solution [mentioned by the author of pipes](http://www.haskellforall.com/2014/02/reasoning-about-stream-programming.html):

> This [..] answers a question people sometimes ask me about `pipes`, which I will paraphase here:
>
> > If resource management is not a core focus of `pipes`, why should I use `pipes` instead of lazy IO?
>
> Many people who ask this question discovered stream programming through Oleg, who framed the lazy IO problem in terms of resource management. However, I never found this argument compelling in isolation; you can solve most resource management issues simply by separating resource acquisition from the lazy IO, like this: [see last example above]

Which brings us back to my previous statement:

> You can simply use `attoparsec` [...][with lazy IO, assuming] that you know the drawbacks of lazy IO.

#### References

- [Iteratee I/O](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Iteratee_I/O), which explains the example better and provides a better overview
- Gabriel Gonzalez (maintainer/author of pipes): [Reasoning about stream programming](http://www.haskellforall.com/2014/02/reasoning-about-stream-programming.html)
- Michael Snoyman (maintainer/author of conduit): [Conduit versus Enumerator](http://www.yesodweb.com/blog/2012/01/conduit-versus-enumerator)

Comment: If you think of lazy I/O as a kind of transparent concurrency, it makes it much easier to think about where problems might arise: if hGetContents forked a thread, it's pretty clear that immediately returning from withFile afterward might not give the thread a chance to finish reading before the file handle is closed.

Answer (score 12):

Here's a great podcast with authors of both libraries:

http://www.haskellcast.com/episode/006-gabriel-gonzalez-and-michael-snoyman-on-pipes-and-conduit/

It'll answer most of your questions.

---

In short, both of those libraries approach the problem of streaming, which is very important when dealing with IO. In essence they manage transferring of data in chunks, 
thus allowing you to e.g. transfer a 1GB file cosuming just 64KB of RAM on both the server and the client. Without streaming you would have had to allocate as much memory on both ends.

An older alternative to those libraries is lazy IO, but it is filled with issues and makes applications error-prone. Those issues are discussed in the podcast.

Concerning which one of those libraries to use, it's more of a matter of taste. I prefer "pipes". The detailed differences are discussed in the podcast too.

Comment: Thanks, I have seen that already. But they don't discuss the issues (atleast in the explicit way) I have outlined on the above question.