# Haskell: Lazy vs. Strict Text values, which one is recommended when?

Tags: haskell, text

I've been doing quite a bit of reading on Data.Text, but I haven't been able to find much in the way of when to prefer Strict over Lazy, or vice-versa.

My understanding is that Data.Text.Strict is a data structure of contiguous characters in memory whereas Data.Text.Lazy is a chunks of contiguous characters.

My question is why shouldn't I always use Data.Text.Lazy? It seems the only overhead is the chunk management, but I don't know if it's noticeable enough? In exchange, concatenation operations can be much cheaper when Text values become large.

Thoughts and insights welcome!

Answer (score 7):

From the docs:

#### [Data.Text.Lazy](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-0.7.2.1/docs/Data-Text-Lazy.html)

> A time and space-efficient implementation of Unicode text using lists of packed arrays. This representation is suitable for high performance use and for streaming large quantities of data. It provides a means to manipulate a large body of text without requiring that the entire content be resident in memory.
>
> Some operations, such as concat, append, reverse and cons, have better complexity than their Data.Text equivalents, due to optimisations resulting from the list spine structure. And for other operations lazy Texts are usually within a few percent of strict ones, but with better heap usage. For data larger than available memory, or if you have tight memory constraints, this module will be the only option.

#### [Data.Text](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-0.7.2.1/docs/Data-Text.html)

> A time and space-efficient implementation of Unicode text using packed Word16 arrays. Suitable for performance critical use, both in terms of large data quantities and high speed.
>
> ...
>
> Most of the functions in this module are subject to fusion, meaning that a pipeline of such functions will usually allocate at most one Text value.

So while `Data.Text` is sufficient for most purposes, `Data.Text.Lazy` is specifically for when you have *very* large amounts of data to process and can't practically hold it all in memory at once.  `Data.Text` is somewhat more efficient in general, but which is better for your application is entirely dependent on your use case.  A good rule of thumb is to start with strict, and if you're having memory or speed problems then try using lazy.

Comment: The conclusion I reach from the quotes you've given is the opposite; *both* are sufficient for most purposes, lazy is much better for some purposes, strict is slightly better for others. Therefore it would make sense to reach for lazy by default to avoid the situation where the wrong choice makes a big difference, and if I end up I the situation where I need to optimise for a few percent more performance (after exhausting all the easy bigger optimizations, presumably) then moving to strict can be one of the options I look at.

Answer (score 6):

I'd say that using `Data.Text.Lazy` inherits many of [the problems of lazy `IO`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5892653/1333025). So my suggestion would be to prefer `Strict`, and if you need to process large pieces of data sequentially, use one of [the available streaming libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9983840/1333025). See also [What is pipes/conduit trying to solve](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22742001/1333025).

Answer (score 0):

Often times, packages for connecting to a database (postgres, redis, etc) only give you strict values; Any lazy values you get from them are created through functions like `Data.Text.Lazy`'s `fromStrict`. In this case, using lazy values adds extra overhead. An example of such a package is `postgresql-simple`.